# Is there a way I can close an exe from python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, exe

I am trying to launch an exe from my python script using

> subprocess

but I want to close/kill it from python script too. Is there any way I can accomplish stopping an exe from python?

PS: My executable stops when I do Alt+F4. I basically want to emulate Alt+F4 programmatically in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you want to call [`Popen.terminate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) or [`Popen.kill()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) on the subprocess.  e.g.:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['path/to/long/runnning/process', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
...
p.terminate()  # kill the process.
```

`Popen.terminate` is a little more gentle -- On POSIX OSs, it'll give the program a chance to handle the signal and do some cleanup vs. `kill` which will try to destroy the process immediately.

Comment: wow, thanks for such a quick reply. Appreciate!! Works like a charm!